# Is there a way for an instance of a Java Outer Class to call all its instances of a Java Inner Class?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, weak-references

With the following code:

```
public class Outer {
    final int foo;

    public Outer(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public Inner createInnerInstance(int bar) {
        return new Inner(bar);
    }

    public int getBarSum() {
        // TODO: implement
    }

    public class Inner {
        final int bar;

        public Inner(int bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public int getBar() {
            return bar;
        }

        public int getFooPlusBar() {
            return foo + bar;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add a method to `Outer` which calls a method on every `Inner`.

One way of doing this is for `Outer` to keep a `List` of `Inner` instances, which `getInnerInstance` appends to.  The problem with this is that I don't want the list's reference to inner instances to keep them from being garbage collected.  Would some form of weakly-linked List be possible in Java?

Are there any different approaches?

Note: I'm only looking for the `Inner`s which share the particular instance of `Outer`.

Comment: pretty sure you need to list them

Comment: a very bad implementation to do that is by adding a global boolean variable to the outer class and having a thread for each of the inner classes that check if the boolean has been changed. You could instead add a listener to each of these classes and invoke the listener from the outer class.

Comment: @nickzoum I acknowledge that but you stated "i was just trying to find a way to signal all the classes without actually having to hold a record for each of the instances." - which I wanted to point out doesn't fit the listener approach. However, since that discussion doesn't help to answer the OP's problem (it partially is based on a misunderstanding on my side) I'll delete my other comments in order not to clutter the question (I'll delete this as well soon, after you had a chance to read it ;) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the outer class doesn't get a reference to the inner classes then there's no (easy) way to do that.

On a simple level think of inner classes having another `this` reference which references the outer class (you'd access it via `Outer.this` in the inner class).

If class A has a reference to an instance of class B but not the other way round the only way to find all instances of A that reference a specfic instance of B would be to iterate over all instances of A and check their B references. And that already starts with the hard part of getting *all* instances of A.

The easier way would be to keep track of the created inner classes, e.g. with a `List<Inner>` inside `Outer`.

Example:

```
class Outer {
  List<Inner> inners = new LinkedList<>();

  public Inner createInnerInstance(int bar) {
    Inner inner = new Inner(bar);
    inners.add( inner );
    return inner;
  }
}
```

If the `Inner` instances can be removed again you'd have to handle that. Of course you could use weaker references like `WeakReference`, `SoftReference` etc. if you just want to get inner instances that *still exist* (you'd have to check the references). However, depending on the size of the inner classes using additional reference instances might not result in better memory usage so use that with care.

Answer (score 1):

A collection of WeakReferences (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) might solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, they are there in Java 6 too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with [WeakReferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), for instance a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).